# sq lserver 2016 ctp3 :Post installation R configuration-error

Tags: r, sql-server-2016

Hi All ,

I have installed sql server 2016 in a windows server to understand the power of the R integration ,now while doing the post installation steps and running the post installation script ,I am continuously getting error

I am using a named instance (changed the name here) ,done the 1st step i.e enabling external script

I am a newbie to the Microsoft platform and by no means a DBA ,so if I missed something ,please point me 
I am running this script in windows powershell (as admin) .Please assist

```
“%programfiles%\RRO\RRO-3.2.2-for-RRE-7.5.0\R-3.2.2\library\RevoScaleR\rxLibs\x64\RegisterRExt” /install /instance:mydb\rinstance
```

I have tried running RegisterRExt from its directory also but the same error keeps popping up.

```
install/instance:mydb\rinstance
At line:1 char:97
+ ... \RegisterRExt"/install/instance:mydb\rinstance
+                    ~
You must provide a value expression following the '/' operator.
At line:1 char:97
+ ... \RegisterRExt"/install/instance:mydb\rinstance
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'install/instance:mydb\rinstance' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpectedValueExpression
```

although running the RegisterRExt executable alone shows me it expects a /install parameter but it does not work .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call RegisterRExt.exe using PowerShell, use the following syntax:

&"${env:programfiles}\RRO\RRO-3.2.2-for-RRE-7.5.0\R-3.2.2\library\RevoScaleR\rxLibs\x64\RegisterRExt.exe" /install /instance:sql_instance_name

This PowerShell command uses the call (&) operator to call RegisterRExt.exe, using an environment variable, and pass it the name of the instance.

For more information, see [Using environment variables with Windows PowerShell](http://blogs.technet.com/b/tip_of_the_day/archive/2014/05/14/tip-of-the-day-using-environment-variables-with-windows-powershell.aspx) and [The CALL Operator](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx).